# The number of ternary strings with even number of $0$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ the number of strings of length $n$ with the alphabet $\{0, 1, 2\}$ such that the number of $0$ in the string is even.

It's not difficult, using generating function or recursions, to show that
$$
a_n = \frac{3^n + 1}{2}.
$$
But if you look at the formula, there seems to be some sort of bijections between the strings of even and odd numbers of $0$. In other words, they should be each of about half of all the ternary strings of length $n$, which is $3^n$. What is the bijection?

Comment: The number of strings with an odd number of zeroes would then be $\frac{3^n-1}2$ (if they are to add to $3^n$, the total number of strings). Not _exactly_ set up for a bijection, but almost.

Comment: @Arthur That's why I suspect there must exist a well-known bijection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the first appearance of either $0$ or $1$ in the string, and swap them. This is an involution that changes the parity of the number of $0$s in the string unless there aren't any $0$s or $1$s to swap, or equivalently unless the string is the all-$2$s string, which has an even number of $0$s. So there's exactly one more string with an even number of $0$s compared to odd.

The same argument applies to an alphabet of a larger size $A$ and gives $a_n = \frac{A^n + (A - 2)^n}{2}$ in that case which also follows from using the multinomial theorem. It comes from generalizing the standard bijective proof that $(1 - 1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} = 0$ which corresponds to the $A = 2$ case.

Comment: Damn. I considered the all-0 string as the odd one out, but thought that would be messy with splitting into cases by the parity of $n$, and still no bijection revealed itself. This is much better.

Comment: The odd string out has to have an even number of $0$s!

Comment: That's obvious now that I know the answer.